# Python: cannot make a HTTPS request using SSL socket

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, https, request

The code tells itself what it does. On all pages I tested I get status code `400`. I tried to specify the certificate or SSL version too but the result is the same. I tried both `closed` and `keep-alive` as `Connection` for the msg sent.

```
import ssl,socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
page='google.com'
s=ssl.wrap_socket(s)
s.connect((page,443))
s.send(("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+page+"/\r\n\r\n").encode('UTF-8'))
while True:
        data=s.recv(4096)
        print(data)
```

Edit: I removed the `/` from the `Host` and it kinda helped, but now I get `301 Moved`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of SSL. In fact, the code 400 says that SSL worked perfectly since otherwise you would not be able to get a HTTP status code in the first place.

The problem is instead that your alleged HTTP request is not a fully correct HTTP request and the server rightly complains about a bad request. You specify `google.com/` as domain inside the `Host` field instead of `google.com`.

Apart from that you fail to properly read the response since you don't stop reading if no more data are available, i.e. this is an endless loop.

> Edit: I removed the / from the Host and it kinda helped, but now I get 301 Moved.

While it is a bad style to just change a question to something different (i.e. make it a moving target)  the code 301 is actually the expected and correct answer from the server. It redirects you from `https://google.com` to `https://www.google.com/`.

Comment: I think it was one of the problems. I made an edit to the post regardless current state.

Comment: @uIM7AI9S: I've also answered this part but please stop making the question a moving target. If you have follow-up questions ask a new one instead. Your original one was fully answered.

Answer (score 1):

there shouldn't be a trailing `/` on the `Host` value, e.g, try doing:

```
s.send(("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+page+"\r\n\r\n").encode('UTF-8'))
```

instead

Comment: I think it was one of the problems. I made an edit to the post regardless current state.